# Duplication of models in foreach/ LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this `foreach` loop that I am running:

```
     @model IList<Employees>
@{ 
    var emp1 = Model.GroupJoin(Model,
                   d => d.DeptId, e => e.Dept.DeptId,
                   (e, d) => new { Emps = e, Dept = d });
}

@foreach (var item in emp1)
{
    <div class="section">
        <h5>@item.Emps.Dept.DeptName</h5>
        <div class="members">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                @{ 
                    var dept1 = item.Dept.OrderByDescending(x => x.ManagerFlag == true);
                }
                @foreach (var dept in dept1)
                {
                   <li class="@(dept.ManagerFlag == true ? "media dotted" : "media")">

                        <img class="mr-3" src="~/images//icons/image.png" alt="">
                        <div class="media-body d-flex">
                            <div class="text" id="liText">

                                <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1"> @dept.Firstname @dept.Lastname</h5>
                                <p>@dept.Title (<span class="loc">@dept.Location.LocationCode</span>)</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="links">
                            <a href="mailto:@dept.Email">
                                <img src="~/images/icons/envelope.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://www.slack.com">
                                <img src="~/images/icons/slack.png" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn archiveButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archivePerson">
                                Archive
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But for some reason the same 'Dept_Names' are displayed multiple times as is the second `foreach` statement. Any reason as to why this is occurring? 
i.e. Emp1 is displaying multiple same dept_names [image]

Thanks

Comment: Post your code rather than a picture. It makes like much easier for us to provide an answer

Comment: `<h5>@item.Emps.Dept.DeptName</h5>` is inside `@foreach (var item in emp1)`, so it is expected to be displayed several times.

Comment: @Andrew yes that is expected, but the same dept.deptnames are being displayed multiple times

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve here?   From the code, it looks like you are trying to loop through a list of employees and display each employee's departments?  But your model appears to have a singular department per employee which contradicts what it appears the code is trying to do.   Are those statements correct?   If not, please detail what you are expecting and also, provide what your Model looks like.

Comment: Yes, for each department there will be multiple employees. This is what is expected. But somehow, departments are being duplicated. @user1011627

Comment: so you are wanting to display a list of departments with employees under them?

Comment: yes that's correct @user1011627

Comment: Hard to tell what the solution is without your model, but from what I can tell without it, you are going about it from the wrong direction and the groupjoin is causing your duplication.   I will add an answer based on what this requirement of dept/emp grouping to see if it helps you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a console application that does what you are wanting...your GroupJoin is causing your duplication.   See if this helps get you going in the right direction.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Department> deps = new List<Department>();
            Department finanace = new Department { Id = 1, Name = "Finance & Accounting" };
            deps.Add(finanace);
            Department hr = new Department { Id = 2, Name = "People - HR" };
            deps.Add(hr);

            List<Employee> emps = new List<Employee>();
            emps.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Finance Person 1", Department = finanace });
            emps.Add(new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Finance Person 2", Department = finanace });
            emps.Add(new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "HR Person 1", Department = hr });
            emps.Add(new Employee { Id = 4, Name = "HR Person 2", Department = hr });


            var grouped =
                deps.GroupJoin(emps,
                   dept => dept,
                   emp => emp.Department,
                   (dept, employeeList) =>
                   new
                   {
                       DepartmentName = dept.Name,
                       Employees = employeeList.Select(employee => employee.Name)
                   });


            foreach (var dept in grouped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dept.DepartmentName);

                foreach (var emp in dept.Employees)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(emp);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }


    public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: what if i wanted to display emp.DepartmentId inside of a div?

Comment: The code I provided is projecting to a new anonymous type that only includes the Name from the Employee object....you'd need to return the entire Employee object  from your GroupJoin.